# Media Element does not paly video from web url in windows phone 8.1 C#

Tags: c#, video, windows-phone-8.1, media-player, mediaelement

I'm working on windows phone app in which I have to run video via web url. I tried much to get this done but not able to do so. [Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff769551%28v=vs.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Media element play local video but not play remote video.

here is my Code:

Xaml:

```
<MediaElement Grid.Row="2" x:Name="player" AutoPlay="False"/>
```

my cs Code:

```
 private async void Play_This_Video(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         // video_url is string.  I convert this to valid url
         // I tried with direct passing string as player source.
         //  My Url looks like this "http://whatsappblog.in/Amazing-Dog-Diving-In-For-Rescue.mp4"

         Uri url = new Uri(video_url);
         player.Source = url;
  }
```

I tried with direct source in xaml but video does not play. like

```
  <MediaElement Grid.Row="2" x:Name="player" source"http://whatsappblog.in/Amazing-Dog-Diving-In-For-Rescue.mp4" AutoPlay="true"/>
```

I tried with mp4 url too. "http://whatsappblog.in/Amazing-Dog-Diving-In-For-Rescue.mp4"

But in all cases video does not play.

then I try to play stream with this code

```
        Uri url = new Uri(video_url);
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
        var file = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(file);

        var randomAccessStream = new MemoryRandomAccessStream(ms);
        //There is an extra class to handle above function.

        player.SetSource(randomAccessStream, "video/mp4");

        player.play();
```

This code does not show any error but video does not play
can you please provide me a solution how to run video file in media element via web url?

Comment: There is no file under your link.

Comment: That is an example. I update link. can you please consider second link for source

Comment: @Stefan I have updated source link. can you please check now.? why this is not working

Comment: `http://whatsappblog.in/Amazing-Dog-Diving-In-For-Rescue.mp4` does not point to a video file. It redirects to `http://funnyvideosdownload.net/`

Comment: Try this link and see if you get some results. The code in your xaml seems ok: https://ia802302.us.archive.org/27/items/Pbtestfilemp4videotestmp4/video_test_512kb.mp4

Comment: In Google chrome I checked that this url is pointing a video. When I run this in browser then this shows me download option.

Comment: ok I try that URL.

Comment: Maybe your chrome browser has an authentication cookie set. To test that you could try to access the video in incognito mode.